# Как передать данные java классу из TextField, которая находится в FXML форме?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

такая проблема.
Есть FXML файл, в которому находится графический интерфейс программы:

```
 <?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.web.WebView?>


  <AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="- 
  Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="453.0" prefWidth="661.0" 
  xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" 
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="browser.Contorleer">
  <children>
  <TextField id="urlField" layoutX="3.0" layoutY="2.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="650.0" promptText="Enter an URL"  onAction="#loadURL" />
  <WebView  id="webViewer" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="30.0" prefHeight="421.0" prefWidth="661.0"  />
  </children>
 </AnchorPane>
```

Есть главный Java класс, из которого запускается приложение: 
    package browser;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.*;

public class webStart extends Application {


WebEngine webEngine;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Browser");
    Parent content = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("web.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(content,661,421);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
}
```

Нужно из FXML файла передать текст введённый в urlField в класс контроллера: 
    package browser;

```
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Contorleer {
@FXML
private TextField urlField;

@FXML
private WebView webViewer;

String message;

public void loadURL(){
    message = urlField.getText();
    System.out.println(message);
}
}
```

Но, когда я ввожу что-то в urlField, программа выбрасывает исключение:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextFieldBehavior.fire(TextFieldBehavior.java:179)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callAction(TextInputControlBehavior.java:178)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.callActionForEvent(BehaviorBase.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.TextInputControlBehavior.callActionForEvent(TextInputControlBehavior.java:127)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.BehaviorBase.lambda$new$74(BehaviorBase.java:135)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.process(Scene.java:3964)
at javafx.scene.Scene$KeyHandler.access$1800(Scene.java:3910)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processKeyEvent(Scene.java:2040)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.keyEvent(Scene.java:2501)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:217)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$KeyEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:149)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleKeyEvent$352(GlassViewEventHandler.java:248)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleKeyEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:247)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleKeyEvent(View.java:546)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyKey(View.java:966)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
... 49 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at browser.Contorleer.loadURL(Contorleer.java:18)
... 59 more
```

Вопрос: Как мне реализовать передачу текста из urlField в класс Controleer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тебе необходимо сеттить в fxml файле для view **fx:id="urlField"**. Этот атрибут **fx:id** необходим для получения view в коде по id.

PS: просто **id** в fxml используеться для настройки стиля view (CSS)

Comment: Всё, я понял, спасибо, очень помогли!))